# Dynamic programming algorithm aka Bellman equation in Robotics?

Tags: research, dynamic-programming

The dynamic programming algorithm refers to the [Bellman equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation). An open-loop control decides movement at the initial point while a closed-loop control decides control during the movement. Now most robotic application looks like closed-loop control: in every point, it checks how it is doing with respect to some reward function, this is my thinking. Now most participants in threads such as [How mature is real-time programming in robotics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-mature-is-real-time-programming-in-robotics) do not differentiate their scope, perhaps they haven't thought about it. Anyway, I am interested to know:

**How is dynamic programming used in robotics? Is there any research about DP usage in robotics?**

Comment: How is "dynamic programming" related to "real-time programming"?

Comment: @Shahbaz *"Dynamic programming"* is a term invented by Bellman, a specific mathematical thing used in academia. The *"real-time programming"* may be or may not be related to it, I don't know. It looks like a term used by some people not understanding some applied mathematics. Can you explain me what you mean by real-time programming? It looks like closed-loop optimization problem.

Comment: [Real-time computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) is not a term used by people who don't understand applied mathematics. Real-time computing/programming is a part of computer science related to implementing and scheduling tasks that have a deadline. In particular, hard real-time tasks should _not_ miss their deadlines under any circumstances. Real-time is often mistaken for "fast", which is an orthogonal concept. Closed-loop control is a very simple example of a real-time task. Dynamic program is a completely unrelated subject.

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer directly how Bellman equation is used in robotics but DP is used in many areas, see the below. Even though we have a dynamic system with velocity/acceleration, we can still use linear-approximation like linear-programming algorithms [here](https://www.ensta-bretagne.fr/jaulin/robotetas.pdf). I provide below some material and lectures about Dynamic programming and robotics. This is pretty interdisciplinary area so hard to find concise description.

**Areas**

> - path-planning
> - vision such as stereo-vision
> - [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) and VCSP problems (see the cognitive robotics below)

**Alert about terminology!**

> The term *"dynamic programming"* is a special term referring to special class of mathematical problems. The term *"dynamic"* system in physics refers to problems in continuum mechanics where objects are not in rest or in constant motion but they can accelerate. Then again [Statics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics) considers problems in stable equilibrium.
>
> The term *"dynamic programming"* is programming for historical reasons but the basic idea is to break the large problem into small problems. It has analogues to fields such as Economics (for example sub-game-perfect equilibrium in game-theory).

**Material**

> **Path-planning**
>
> - [Minimax Diﬀerential Dynamic Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20180720125532/https://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Chris.Atkeson/legs/xmorimo.pdf)
> - [Efﬁcient Dynamic Programming for Optimal Multi-Location Robot Rendezvous](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emitchell/Papers/publishedCDC08.pdf)
> - [A dynamic programming approach to trajectory planning of robotic manipulators](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1104317)
> - [Dynamic Programming Algorithms for Planning and Robotics in Continuous Domains and the Hamilton-Jacobi Equation](https://ramp.ensc.sfu.ca/fmmtutorial/slides/mitchell.pdf)
>
> **Vision, Stereo vision and Dynamic programming**
>
> - [Dynamic programming stereo vision algorithm for robotic applications](http://www.cipprs.org/papers/VI/VI1999/pp117-124-Gonzalez-et-al-1999.pdf)
> - [Stereo by Intra- and Inter-Scanline Search Using Dynamic Programming](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4767639)
>
> **[Lectures](https://search.mit.edu/search?site=ocw&client=mit&getfields=*&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=http://ocw.mit.edu/search/google-ocw.xsl&proxyreload=1&as_dt=i&oe=utf-8&departmentName=web&courseName=&q=robotics%20dynamic%20programming&btnG.x=-595&btnG.y=-267)**
>
> - Underactuated robotics in MIT [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-832-underactuated-robotics-spring-2009/)
>   -- this lecture [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-832-underactuated-robotics-spring-2009/resources/lecture-5-numerical-optimal-control-dynamic-programming/)
>   about DP
> - Cognitive robotics has some tasks about DP [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130701192554/http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-412j-cognitive-robotics-spring-2005/assignments/ps2.pdf)

Comment: In the 1950s when dynamic programming came into existence, the term "programming" was often used synonymously with "optimization". This was the case with "dynamic programming".